# Flex databinding a function

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-binding

Does anyone know how to programmatically bind a property to a function that isn't a getter? IE: I have a function that returns a translated string based on the identifier you pass it.  How do I do this in AS3 rather than MXML? (reason being - I have a dynamic layout that I render based on XML and so have create and add all children programmatically).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bind the result of a function, you will have to mention the type of event that will be triggered when the function's result changes (see point 2).

```
private var foo:int;

[Bindable(event="myCustomFunctionBinding")]
public function myFunction():String
{
    return "This is foo :" + foo;
}
```

Then, when you want all elements to update the binded value, you must dispatch the event yourself :

```
private function bar():void
{
    foo++;
    dispatchEvent(new Event("myCustomFunctionBinding"));
}
```

In which case, you can bind like this :

```
<mx:TextArea text="{myClass.myFunction()}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a setter function using `BindingUtils.bindSetter()`. You can use this to call a setter function that calls your translation function and sets the return value to a specified place. Unfortunately you can't dynamically specify the host of the setter like you can with `BindingUtils.bindProperty()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but I've done something similar this way:

Say you've declared a Label using your function:

```
<mx:Label text="{LocaleUtil.getMessage('label.description')}"/>
```

That `getMessage` function reads a XML file depending on the selected Locale.

If the user changes the Locale, you should call `executeChildBindings(true)` on any container or on the whole application:

```
this.parentApplication.executeChildBindings(true);
```

That will force every child `UIComponent` to execute the bindings again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to be honest I managed to resolve this one myself by doing:

```
public function loadStringBinding(aIdentifier:String, aField:UIComponent, aProperty:String, aAddtlChars:String = null):Function 
{
    return function():void {
        var str:String;
        if(aAddtlChars)
        {
            str = aAddtlChars;
        }
        else
        {
            str = '';
        }
    if(_localePacks.get(currentLocale))
    {
        if(XML(_localePacks.get(currentLocale)).translatedString.(@identifier==aIdentifier).@translation.toString().length > 0)
        {
            aField[aProperty] =  XML(_localePacks.get(currentLocale)).translatedString.(@identifier==aIdentifier).@translation + str;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            aField[aProperty] =  aIdentifier + str;
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //TODO: Replace with webservice call to get individual string
    }

    aField[aProperty] =  'No locale pack' + str; 
    return;
    }
}
```

What this does is return the function that it gets bound to, so I can pass it which ever component I want the property go get bound to.  It is implemented like:

```
_currentWatchers.addItem(BindingUtils.bindSetter(LocaleManager.instance().loadStringBinding('firstName, myCFormItem, 'label', '*'), LocaleManager.instance(), 'newLocale'));
```

I'm sure that it doesn't really make sense to anyone seeing as the rest of the code isn't here and it's a bit involved of an application, but just know that the solution is that the bindSetter function takes a funciton as the first parameter, so I created a function that creates a function that executes the binding that I wanted. If that makes sense to anyone else.. awesome!  Thanks for anyone who contributed though!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind functions to any event that is dispatched when the property changes. use the addEventListener() member method to add a handler. Read the Flex 3.0 documentation [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_4.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since functions are object in actionscript3.0, you may add properties to them, the same as you would any other object,

```
var f : Function = function() : void{ 
   trace("Value of testProp: " + arguments.callee.testProp ); 
};
(f as Object).testProp = 'TESTING';
f();
```

*arguments.callee* is used like the *this* keyword. *arguments.callee* holds a reference to the function it is used inside of.

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but this is how you would add a property to a function.

**I'm sorry I think i got it backwards, you want to add a function to a property, not add a property to a function. O well, hope you enjoy this post anyway.**